# tkinterのTextウィジェットに色々な関数からの作業状況を表示したい

Tags: python, tkinter

Windows10，JupyterLab で Python 3 を使っています。

お尋ねしたいのは，様々な関数の作業結果をTextウィジェットにリアルタイム表示する方法です。例えば

（１）メインウインドウのボタンをクリックすると，
・新しいウインドウ（Text ウィジェット付き）を出力する。
・関数1を実行する。
・関数2を実行する。
（２）関数1の処理が終わったら，メッセージを Text ウィジェットに書き込む。
（３）関数2の処理が終わったら，メッセージを Text ウィジェットに書き込む。

というものです。以下のようなプログラムを作りましたが，うまくいきません。

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

def start():
    th0 = threading.Thread(target=status_window)
    th0.start()
    process1()
    process2()    

def status_window():
    global info
    progress = tk.Toplevel(root)
    progress.geometry("500x200")
    progress.title("途中経過")
    progress.grab_set()
    progress.focus_set()
    info = tk.Text(progress)
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(progress, orient="vertical", command=info.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    info["yscrollcommand"] = scrollbar.set
    info.pack(side="top", fill="both")    

def process1():
    time.sleep(2) # 実際の作業の代わり
    msg = "処理1が終わりました。\n"
    info.insert("end", msg)
    info.see("end")

def process2():
    time.sleep(2) # 実際の作業の代わり
    msg = "処理2が終わりました。"
    info.insert("end", msg)
    info.see("end")

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="start", command=start)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

イメージとしては，ボタンを押すとすぐにウインドウ「途中経過」が現れ，2秒待って（関数1の作業時間のつもり）「処理1が終わりました」，更に2秒後に「処理2が終わりました」が書き込まれる，というものです。

しかし，このコードではボタンを押して4秒経ってから，何も書かれていないウインドウ「途中経過」が現れ，エラーメッセージ
NameError: name 'info' is not defined
が出ます。

ただし，このエラーメッセージは1度目の実行時のものです。「途中経過」ウインドウを閉じ，メインウインドウも閉じ，改めて実行すると（同じセルで shift + Enter），今度はエラーメッセージが
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!text"
になります。3度目以降も同様です。

どうすれば各関数の処理が終わるごとにメッセージが表示されるようになるでしょうか。
また，どうすればエラーが出なくなるでしょうか。

ご存じの方，ご教示をお願い致します。

Comment: 色々と突っ込みどころがありますが、大きな原因の一つはこれでしょう。[打倒、Pythonのグローバル宣言](https://qiita.com/karageman/items/08c4979748a8654e4dc5) あと何故、別ウインドウを別スレッドで作る必要があるのでしょうか？ この質問程度の内容であれば全てメインで処理するか、あるいは表示処理をメイン側で行って関数をスレッドにするとかの方が簡単ではないですか？ もしくはステータスウインドウはあらかじめメイン側で別に作っておくけれども、必要があるまで非表示にしておくとか？ それでも独立した何かにしておきたいなら、ウィジェットを直接共有するのではなく、[queue --- 同期キュークラス](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/queue.html) でメッセージを渡すだけにするとか？ [How to thread with tkinter in python3 using queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54472639/9014308)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

全てメインで処理とは，start() を

    def start():
        status_window()
        process1()
        process2()

に，関数の側をスレッドとは

    def start():
        status_window()
        th1 = threading.Thread(target=process1)
  th1.start()
  th2 = threading.Thread(target=process2)
  th2.start()

にすることだと思い，回答します。

前者では全て終わってからウインドウが出るだろうから，一方をmainloopとは別のスレッドに任せるべきと考えました。

後者は，実は本当の作業は関数が10を超えそうなのですが，そんなにスレッドを作れるのか，同期処理を正確に行えるのかが不安だったため，ウインドウ出力を別スレッドにしました。試しに後者を試したら，ウインドウはすぐ出ますが，コメントは2つまとめて出力されました。何か問題があるようです。

グローバル宣言とqueueについては，勘違いや無知だったところがありそうですので，先に勉強してみます。